# Create PDF file without having to save locally

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, matplotlib

I have a flask API deployed as a container on AWS Lightsail where I'm using the PdfPages class from matplotlib's [backend_pdf](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_pdf_api.html#module-matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf) to save figures to a pdf file.
The PdfPages class takes a filename as an argument, writes the data to the file, and saves the file locally. An example is shown below:

```
with PdfPages('foo.pdf') as pdf:
fig = plt.figure()
pdf.savefig(fig)
pdf.savefig()
```

My question is this: How can I save all the figures and return them as part of the response from the server?

My initial solution was to save the figure objects to a list and return the list like so:

```
fig_list = []
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig_list.append(fig)
response = {'figures': fig_list}
return jsonify(response)
```

The problem with this is that the Figure object is not JSON serializable and therefore I can't return the list as part of my response from the API. What other ways can I achieve this without having to create and save a pdf file?